# WPF standalone local database without server installation

Tags: wpf, local-database

I developed a WPF application which is connected Sql Server and works very well,now I want embed a database to my application which don't require any server installation.I want anybody just click setup.exe and install in their computer.

---

Comment: And so you want something that supports multithreading, is that it? What do you mean exactly by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does support Multi-Threading ([SQLite And Multiple Threads](http://sqlite.org/threadsafe.html)) and it doesn't require installation so it meets all your requirements...

> SQLite support three different threading modes:
>
> Single-thread. In this mode, all mutexes are disabled and SQLite is
>   unsafe to use in more than a single thread at once.
>
> Multi-thread. In this mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple
>   threads provided that no single database connection is used
>   simultaneously in two or more threads.
>
> Serialized. In serialized mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple
>   threads with no restriction.
>
> The threading mode can be selected at compile-time (when the SQLite
>   library is being compiled from source code) or at start-time (when the
>   application that intends to use SQLite is initializing) or at run-time
>   (when a new SQLite database connection is being created). Generally
>   speaking, run-time overrides start-time and start-time overrides
>   compile-time. Except, single-thread mode cannot be overridden once
>   selected.
>
> The default mode is serialized.

Comment: I highly recommend this option.  I had to use SQLite in a similar situation to OP's and it is working out beautifully.